# Force mobile version of website for WebView

Tags: java, android, mobile, webview

I'm loading an URL into a webview to display it into my app. The problem I'm encountering is, that not always the site recognizes that I'm a phone (why so ever?). How exactly do I force the webview to send to the site that I'm a mobile phone? Currently I'm doing it like that

`webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");`

But that doesn't work? Won't it work because I'm not using an iPhone? I don't think that this is the reason since it's just setting the user Agent...

This is the relevant code (the irelevant code just contains data such as getting an url from an intent and formatting a string )

```
//package

//imports

public class WebViewing extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    //init strings

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewer);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //init variables

        //get intent data and format string


        this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3"); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        dialog.setMessage("Website wird geladen...\nDies ist abh\u00E4ngig von deiner Internet-Verbindung.");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
        webview.loadUrl(sourceURL);
        setTitle("Platz: " + plusRank + " - " + realDate);

    }

    //onCreateOptionsMenu method

    //onOptionsItemSelected method
}
```

I also tried out this string for the user agent

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620754/how-to-force-mobile-version-of-a-page-webview i tried it but didnt help me .
any other suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try to put these following lines :-

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
```

Comment: Seems like enabling JavaScript fixed the problem. :) Thanks

Comment: Setting the user agent string may or may not fix the issue, it all depends what user agent string the site is looking for. It probably does this using JavaScript, which is why enabling JavaScript is more likely to fix issues reliably

Answer (score 1):

I know I am too late to the party. But, hoping it will help someone who is still facing the same problem, I will write my solution here.

The accepted answer *didn't work* for me. The following does.

Java:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
```

Kotlin:

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
```