# Mobile version do not work on a WebView

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-webview

I'm showing a WebView in an Activity but instead of showing the mobile version of the site is showing the desktop version. If I open the same URL with Android browser it shows the mobile version but not in my WebView.

I have already checked the usual solutions for similar problems:

Setting User-Agent:
[Android WebView Not Loading Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166228/android-webview-not-loading-mobile-site)

Enabling javascript:
[Force mobile version of website for WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680979/force-mobile-version-of-website-for-webview)

I guess there is something different in the server I'm accessing. A sample URL is:
http://www.marca.com/2014/07/30/futbol/futbol_internacional/1406714623.html

My code is here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = b.getString("url");

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    theWebView = new WebView(this);
    layout.addView(theWebView);
    setContentView(layout);

    String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
    theWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    theWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
    theWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    theWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    if (url!=null){
        theWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this site you're viewing a site that you made, or is it someone else's? If you have access to the source code, you could consider restyling it with something like Bootstrap - essentially, it reformat's the html layout of a site so that It will look nice on screens of various sizes (i.e., if you shrink the browser window, or view it on a mobile device).

Comment: It's a news source, not under my control. The thing is that if a browser shows mobile version, I guess WebView should also be able to show it.

Comment: @poqueque you had any luck with this?

Comment: It's been seven years.... cannot remember... 